# For a PID $R,$ what is the rank of the submodule given by $S=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in R^n: x_1 +\cdots +x_n=0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

Let $R$ be a PID and $R^n$ be the free $R$-module of rank $n.$ Now consider the $R$-submodule of $R^n$ given by $$S=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in R^n: x_1 +\cdots +x_n=0\}.$$ 
We know that $S$ is a free $R$-module of rank less than or equal to $n.$ In particular when $R$ is a field then $S$ is of rank $n-1.$ In general can we prove that $\text{rank}(S)=n-1$ ?

Comment: Hint: $x \in S \longmapsto (x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}) \in R^{n-1}$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Have you tried finding a basis for $S$?

Comment: @Mindlack: Don't  we need $R$ to be PID ?

Comment: Not for so simple a module, it seems.